# Running a php file

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I'm trying to run a html form that uses php to submit the user data to a database.  What do I need to use tor run and test my program since it is a php file.

Comment: You need a web server and PHP librarys to make it work.

Comment: And he need to install PHP on his environment and the libraries to make it work.

Comment: Going by the scant detail in the question, to test, they'll need a minimum of Php and a 'database' - with corresponding Php libraries for connectivity.  They can use Php's inbuilt server for development and testing - no need for a full blown web server.  Have you decided which database you wish to use?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php) for how to set up and start using php on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is windows install xampp and place your php files in htdocs.
or wampp and place your php files in www.

If it is Linux your may use lampp or install separately php and a http server (apache or nginx).

In any case you have to start the http server and then access them on browser using localhost/yourfile.php

And you also should set up your database if your system requires it. Xampp, Wampp and Lampp uses mysql by default, but by your tags I guess your are using sql server. So you have to install and config it.

Comment: Thank you so much!